# Can't link image src from folder

Tags: javascript

```js
const bannerData = [{
    "title": "My title",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molest",
    "image_url": "./assets/bg-1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "My title2",
    "description": "dwadawdwa",
    "image_url": "https://img2.storyblok.com/f/89778/1168x728/578a7ddf01/us_us-ny_nyc_1.jpeg"
  }
]

function initBanner(currentSlide) {
  banner.style.backgroundImage = `url('${bannerData[currentSlide].image_url}')`
  textBoxHeading.textContent = `${bannerData[currentSlide].title}`
  textBoxDescription.textContent = `${bannerData[currentSlide].description}`
}
```

Whenever I do in my index.html
`<img src="./assets/bg-1.jpg">` then I am seeing the image in my html. But whenever I try to load the background for element with js then it wont load at all. I have to use url in order for it to work. Why is this happening and how can I link backgrounds from my folder instead from url's? I am not getting any errors in console, and just have white blank screen with no img.

[image]

Comment: @mplungjan tried it as well, still doesn't load.

Comment: Do you have some kind of module bundler in the project?

Comment: @octaviandd Yes, I just installed parcel js

Comment: You need to use the path where the assets are being bundled. For example, if you have a build folder and in there you have index.js and /assets/images, your path will be /assets/images. In other words, your code will be bundled in one file and this where your relative path starts from.

Comment: @octaviandd Thanks, seems to work when I do it this way `"image_url": "bg-1.a56b5a52.jpg"` it's in my `dist/` folder, do you know if I can change the `a56b5a52.jpg` in any way with the bundler?

Comment: Alternatively, in case the issue remains, a workaround could be to do something like `window.location.host + ${bannerData[currentSlide].image_url}`. Not perfect, but at least you don't have to hard code the url.

Comment: I know with webpack you can do this very easily, however with parcel you need to code a bit more, https://parceljs.org/plugin-system/namer/ .